# ga goal conversion after redirect

Tags: google-analytics, google-oauth

My service (wellybox dot com) is grabbing invoices from email services (gmail / o365).  the flow is:

landing page -- > connect google (via gmail oauth flow) --> see all financial docs (that's the goal)

as the users are going through http://account.google.com for the oauth flow, all the conversion goals are marked as coming from account.google.com and not the original traffic source.

How can I configure ga so it will show the original traffic source (e.g. fb / Expensify / QuickBooks)?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Admin -> Property Settings -> Tracking info -> Referral Exclusion List and enter: accounts.google.com

Comment: thanks.   I got this message (for people to look in the future):

'These settings only work with the analytics.js version of the tracking code. If you’re using the ga.js version, configure these settings in your code. If you’re transitioning to analytics.js from ga.js, customize these settings to match your previous configuration for data continuity.'

Comment: Sure, however ga.js has been considered deprecated for several years: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/upgrade if someone has the problem you described today I don't think he noticed it after years, therefore I doubt he has the legacy version.